# Como eu faço para excluir um arquivo de uma pasta em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

o código abaixo lista os arquivos de um determinado diretório, queria saber como eu faço para excluir apenas 1 arquivo deste diretorio

```
 def etc():
     path ="diretorio"`
     dir = os.listdir(path)
     for file in dirs:
         print(file)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para remover um arquivo, você pode utilizar a função [`os.remove(path)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove) :

```
import os

def etc():
    path = "diretorio"`
    dir = os.listdir(path)
    for file in dir:
        if file == "arquivo.txt":
            os.remove(file)
```

O exemplo acima exclui o arquivo `arquivo.txt` se encontrá-lo no diretório.

> **Atenção**: no seu código, você atribui a lista de arquivos ao objeto `dir`, mas executa o `for` sobre o objeto `dirs`. Certifique-se que o nome dos dois objetos sejam iguais para que o código funcione como o esperado.

Comment: no caso eu queria criar como se fosse um input() , porque depois de listados eu poderia excluir um especifico, nao sei se me entendeu

Comment: Então acredito que você consiga fazer sozinho a partir de agora. Mantenha seu código para listar os arquivos, requisite ao usuário o nome do arquivo que será excluído com `input` e remova-o com `os.remove`.

Answer (score 0):

> import os
>
> def limpar():
>
> ```
> pasta = "diretorio"
> arquivo = str(input('digite o nome do arquivo que deseja apagar: '))
> diretorio = os.listdir(pasta)
> if arquivo in diretorio:
>     print('---removendo arquivo----')
>     os.remove('{}/{}'.format(pasta, arquivo))
>     print('%s removido da pasta %s' % (pasta, arquivo))
> else:
>     print('este arquivo nao existe')
> ```